# Código não compila com diversos erros

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OrdenaArgumentos {
    String [] nomes = new String []{ " rafael cosentino ", " jonas hirata ", " marcelo martins "};
    java.util.Arrays.sort (nomes);

     for ( String nome : nomes ) {
     System . out. println ( nome );
     }
}
```

Comment: Podia adicionar mais informações sobre o problema?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
 - Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
  FormalParameterList
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Erros de sintaxe na sentença java.util.Arrays.sort (nomes);

Comment: O ponto de .sort está sublinhado em vermelho e (nomes); também.

Comment: Você pode sempre [Editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/103587/edit) a sua pergunta para adicionar essas e outras informações adicionais relevantes que possam ajudar a resolver o problema. O link de edição está logo abaixo da sua pergunta a seguir às `tags`. Se precisar de ajuda na formatação do texto e código, acesse: [Ajuda no Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) e também - [formatar publicações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou declarar o método, sem ele não vai funcionar mesmo.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class OrdenaArgumentos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] nomes = new String []{ " rafael cosentino ", " jonas hirata ", " marcelo martins "};
        java.util.Arrays.sort(nomes);
        for (String nome : nomes) System.out.println(nome);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CNUwM5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bizdgxsk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Declaring.java).